# Upgrading Radiant to Rails 2.3.9+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

Has anyone had luck upgrading the vendored Rails version to 2.3.9 or above? Right now I'm stuck at 2.3.8 and moving up to 2.3.9 or above breaks the extension loading.

The master branch seems to be stuck at 2.3.8 as well which was updated in May of last year. Almost a year ago!

Answer (score 1):

There is Radiant with Rails 3 branch in github https://github.com/radiant/radiant/tree/rails3 However this is not a stable version, it is still work in progress. They are working on this. If you are keen, you may contribute to this branch as well. In the end it may come.

I was choosing between Radiant and Refinery CMS recently, and in the end I have to choose Radiant due to the two's architecture design difference. I have written an article on this as well
http://www.shanison.com/2011/03/29/radiant-cms-vs-refinery-cms/

Comment: We currently have a branch of Radiant and I wasn't able to upgrade it past 2.3.8 without major problems loading extensions. We are looking to move it to Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2 but now it seems Radiant development is stagnant. We will be migrating to Refinery later this year.

Comment: I agree that Radiant's development right now seems like stagnant. However, I can't move to Refinery becoz of the single layout issue with Refinery.

Comment: Yeah, that is going to be an issue with us as well. I'm going to be extending the pages engine in a couple ways. I'll post here with my pages branch if you are interested.

Comment: I would love to see that. Thanks